Prove n-sphere is homogeneous without constructing orthogonal transformations?
To prove that the Euclidean $n$-sphere $S^n$ is topologically homogeneous, it suffices to show that if $q \in S^n$, there is a homeomorphism $h$ of $S^n$ with $h(q) = p$ (or vice versa), where $p = (1, 0, 0, ..., 0)$ is the north pole of $S^n$.
I know that one can readily prove that $S^n$ is topologically (and, for that matter, metrically) homogeneous by constructing an appropriate orthogonal transformation carrying $p$ to given $q$ (or vice versa), but that involves more linear algebra than I'd like for my purposes.
Is there some other simple way to establish that $S^n$ is homogeneous? (I do not need $h$ to be an isometry!)

Describing self homeomorphisms of the sphere that are not isometries is going to be more complicated than working with isometries.
However, if you are interested, you can consider the sphere as a 2 point compactification of an infinite cylinder. Translation along the cylinder's axis converts to a self homeomorphism of the sphere with two fixed points, say at two opposing poles. This type of transformation along various axes plus simple rotations around axes will do the trick.

Similarly to the above comment, given a point $o$ different from $p,q$, you can view $S^n$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $o$. Then the map $v\mapsto v-p+q$ is a linear, hence continuous map on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which extends continuously to the sphere by fixing $o$.

@UriGeorgePeterzil: Please make this an Answer, so I can accept it.

@UriGeorgePeterzil: the proof in your answer has an enormous gap - see my comment to it.

Answer appears in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4940061/32337

We can see $S^n$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.
Take the (only) plane $\pi $ that passes through the origin, $q$ and $p$. Then, $\pi\cap S^n$ is a circle which contains $q$ and $p$.
Let $h$ be the rotation on that circle that maps $q$ to $p$. This rotation can be extended to the whole of $S^n$: for every other point $q'$ we can construct the circle on $S^n$ that goes through $q'$ and $p$ and rotate as much as we did for $q$.
This map is continuous and its inverse, which consists on undoing the rotation, is too.
This proves that $S^n$ is topologically homogeneous.

This would take some detail to verify the continuity claim.

Similarly to the comment given above, given any point $o\neq p,q$, we can view $S^n$ as the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $o$. Then the map $v\mapsto v−p+q$ is a linear, hence continuous map on $\mathbb{R}^n$ which extends continuously to the sphere by fixing the point $o$.

I think this answer is begging the question by asserting that, for any given point $o \in S^n$, "we can view $S^2$ as the one-point compactiication of $\mathbb{R}^n$ at $o$." That's OK when $o = p$, the north pole (or south pole), for the stereographic projection is a homeomorhpism between the dense subset $S^n \setminus {o}$ of the compact space $S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$. But how do you do it for $o \neq p$ (and $o \neq q$)?
